# Magento 2 - How to debug Repository SQL?

Tags: magento2, customer-address

How to debug generated sql query/s from repository.

i need to debug: `$this->addressRepo->getList($cirteria)->getSearchCriteria();` on this example.

```
public function getSuperUserCompanyAddresses(){
    $objectManager =   ObjectManager::getInstance();
    /**
     * @var $criteria SearchCriteriaBuilder
     * @var $filter_1 FilterBuilder
     */
    $criteria = $objectManager->create(SearchCriteriaBuilder::class);
    $filter_1 = $objectManager->create(FilterBuilder::class);

    $filters[] = $filter_1
        ->setField(self::ADDRESS_COMPANY_KEY)
        ->setConditionType('eq')
        ->setValue((int) ($this->getCustomAttribute('company_id')->getValue()) )
        ->create();

    $cirteria = $criteria->addFilters($filters)->create();
    /**
     * @var $addresses \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface[]|null
     */
    $addresses = $this->addressRepo->getList($cirteria)->getSearchCriteria();

    $this->setAddresses($addresses);
    return parent::getAddresses();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below command to log the queries and find the generated query logs in var/debug/db.log after refreshing the page, also remember that it logs all queries on the page, by looking at query you can debug further

```
bin/magento dev:query-log:enable
```